# How do I get classic page search back for Opera 10.5?

Tags: opera

I have upgraded to [Opera](http://www.opera.com/) 10.51 (from Opera 9.64).

How do I get search in a page (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) to use a dialog box (as in 9.64) instead of the modal jumping around? (I have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> in order to be able navigate with the arrow keys again and this clears the highlight of a match).

Comment: Can't find such thing in preferences nor about:config. I guess it's an "improved feature" only, and no way to get the old one back.

Comment: I find my arrow keys still work after it's started searching.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can find to have a bit of the behavior you need back, is to press 3 times <kbd>Tab</kbd>, to get the focus back on the page. Then it allows you to scroll with the arrow keys while keeping highlighting, but that's all.

Comment: Thanks, that is an improvement and can work as a work-around. It takes care of the modalness. One can then scroll a match to the beginning or bottom of the window so it is easier to spot after ESC has been pressed (ESC will result in some amount of scrolling because the bar with the search term disappears).